# Import Android Existing Project Error

Tags: android, eclipse, android-actionbar

I'm trying to import ActionBar-PullToRefresh library in my workspace.

I clone project from github. After that I try to import pic.1.

[image]

I got error like this,

[image]

And added just one project into Eclipse.

Therefore I couldn't start project. What should I do for fix this problem ?

Regards,
Emre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a project (check the left hand side of the second image) called `MainActivity`.

Thus, a quick fix would be to change the name of that project to a more descriptive one. :)

--

Side note: You should consider moving to [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html) and using [Gradle](http://gradle.org) for your dependency management.

Comment: First image I see 3 Main Activity all of them different project. Normally I'm thinking all of them import same time. Is it?

I'm try try try but I can't import Android Studio. Normally this project wrote with Android Studio with dependency but I try to open Project Structure in Android Studio I got error "We will provide a UI to configure project settings later. Until then, please manually edit your build.gradle file(s).

Do you have any idea about this error ? 

http://i39.tinypic.com/5pq87o.png

Comment: That's a good question - I'd create a new question regarding the build.gradle error and get help that way. You'll probably need to copy&paste the contents of that file into the new post. :)

Comment: (By the way, the three different MainActivity projects are sample projects, which (if I'm not mistaken) creates a workspace directory called MainActivity, which then will be occupied by the first project, causing the other two imports to fail)

Comment: Thank you so much.. I'm updating my Android Studio after that try to import. Thank you again for your help.. See you next question :)